# How to redirect a request to another URL on json-server?

Tags: javascript, frontend, json-server

I need to request paginated data from json-server. I want to retrieve a page of users containing 10 results for each page. For this, I am making a `GET` request to `/posts/page/1`, but I know I need to request it like `/posts?_start=0&_end=9` because this is the way json-server works.

The problem is that my real backend works like that, and both requests should be done the same way from frontend, regardless if I am using my real backend server or my test json-server.

I tried to use `routes.json` but I cant see a way to add logic to convert the page number to the `_start` and `_end` parameters on `routes.json` since it is a json file.

I just need json-server to return response from `/posts?_start=0&_end=9` everytime I request `/trips/page/1`, again, with logic to convert the page number to the `_start` and `_end` parameters.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`_page`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#paginate) with `_limit` instead of `_start`/`_end`.

Then add to [routes.json](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes) like:

```
{
  "/:type/page/:page": "/:type?_page=:page&_limit=10"
}
```

Which should handle `/posts/page/1` or `/trips/page/1`.

Comment: Tough it would be good to know how to modify requests to json-server before it reaches its the json-server itself as I asked, this solved my problem. No need to implement any logic for pagination. I don't know why I looked to Slice instead of Pagination on json-server documentation. Thank you.

Comment: np, you could put express in front or just use express, the json-server tool is for dev and mocking

Comment: There is examples in the docs to "modify requests to json-server", https://github.com/typicode/json-server#module

Answer (score 1):

If anyone landed here like me looking for how to redirect to a different url on json-server, this is how:

```
server.get('/redirect', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/my_other_url')
})
```